# Multithreading sockets timeout?

Tags: c++, sockets, c++11

I use c++11 thread library and sockets. 
I create thread for every socket.

```
void connect_server(...)
{
    //here socket (stream client) stuff with connecting, receiving and sending data
}

int main()
{
    //...
    for (...)
        container.push_back(std::thread(connect_server, params));

    for (...)
        thread.join();
    //...
}
```

how can I check if connection is timeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a variant you can use [setsockopt()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setsockopt) to setup timeout value using SO_SNDTIMEO SO_RCVTIMEO. When socket unblocks after timeout expired you can send a signal to main process, simply finish child thread or anything else.
[Here](http://unix.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.unix.programmer/2008-06/msg00108.html) a tiny snippet on how to setup connection timeout using select() call.

Comment: I want to set connect timeout not recv or send timeout.

Comment: @user2962442 Then you can set socket to non-blocking operation mode and use select() with timeout?

Comment: @user2962442 I just mentioned that you're using C++11. And I proposed C-style. Don't know if it is critical to you. But yeah, it works well in multithreaded apps. Moreover using select() for all your sockets you can just get rid of multithreading in some cases - all the sockets file descriptors should be used in select() call and then appropriately processed with FD_ISSET().